# can I delete a phpmyadmin database locally on a shared project?

Tags: wordpress, phpmyadmin

I'm new to wordpress, and I'm wondering if there is any harm in deleting a phpmyadmin database for a shared project?  I was working on a wordpress site for an old job and imported their database into my phpmyadmin, and now since I no longer work there I'd like to delete it and not have it on my localhost. I assume that it would be fine to delete without disrupting anything since it is just local but can't find the answer anywhere and want to be sure.  Thanks!

Comment: Yes! if you don't want it anymore then you should probably delete it.

Comment: You should not delete the database because if it is still used, you will not be able to restore it once deleted. I advise you to rename the database and if you don't get errors, then you can delete it safely. If you get errors about a database not found, then it means that the database is still in use.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's absolutely fine. If the db is not being used by anything else you require then go ahead and delete it.